# Sendmail inserting ! symbol in middle of email after 990 characters

Tags: html, linux, email, sendmail

I am sending mail from sendmail using sendmail -v rohit@XXXXXXX.com < t.txt
But when i receive the mail using outlook or gmail i get an extra ! character after exactly 990 characters https://infoeu.!mytotalconnectcomfort.com. I dont understand why the extra character is inserted by sendmail!! ?

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=utf-8/></head><body><p>Dear Mr/Ms scure dhf</p><p>Thank you for choosing XXXXXXX.</p><p> In order to live a fulfilling experience with your newly purchased XXXXXXX system, please read carefully the following guidance.</p><p> <strong>1. Domonial owners</strong></p><p>To remotely operate your system, please access the following Internet address: <u><a href=https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/>https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/</a></u></p><p> Your login is: sucre567</p><p> Your password is: sucre567</p><p><strong>2. Sucre Box and Sucre Box + owners</strong></p><p> Sucre Box and Sucre Box + owners can live a fulfilling experience by installing our latest Total Connect Comfort International smartphone application available for both Android phones and IPhones.</p><p> <strong><em>2.1  If you want to use the application</em></strong></p><p> Connect to <u><a href=https://infoeu.mytotalconnectcomfort.com/>https://infoeu.!
     mytotalconnectcomfort.com</a></u></p><p>Create an account or login if you already have one</p><p> Access the security section and follow the instructions</p><p>The security login and password will be requested:</p><p>Security login: sucre567</p><p>Security password: sucre567</p><p> And don&#146;t forget to download the app on your smartphone!</p><p><strong><em>2.2  If you don&#146;t want to use the application</em></strong></p><p>To set up and remotely operate your system, please access the following Internet address: <u><a href=https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/>https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/</a></u></p><p>Your login is: sucre567</p><p>Your password is: sucre567</p><p><strong>3.  Sucre GPRS owners</strong></p><p>To set up and remotely operate your system, please access the following Internet address: <u><a href=https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/>https://tc20e.total-connect.eu/</a></u></p><p>Your login is: sucre567</p><p> Your password is: sucre567</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SMTP protocol line length limit

[SMTP RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) specifies limits on maximum length of message line.
Sendmail breaks long lines to avoid crossing the limit.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.6

**FIXES to choose from**:
1 . You seem to send html context.  You may use `tidy` program to reformat your html. It should also break long html lines.
2. You can send using `quoted-printable` enconding. It encodes non ASCII characters and takes care of line lengths.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence is longer than 990 characters sendmail or mail inserts an ! mark. To avoid the problem break the sentence using \r\n and then encode the same to %0D%0A (equivalent of \r\n). The problem is then gone. Also, we can modify /etc/mail/sendmail.cf L=990 to some larger value this will also solve the problem.
Line from sendmail.cf
P=[IPC], F=mDFMuX, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=EnvToSMTP, E=\r\n, L=990, T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,A=TCP $h

Answer (score 1):

Using the fold command is also a way to add line wraps to avoid this problem.